# Use a BaseScript in a groovy class gives Annotation @BaseScript can only be used within a script

Tags: groovy, interface

I am comming from Java background and try to use little Groovy. I would like to create a Groovy class which follows specific interface :

```
import groovy.transform.BaseScript
@BaseScript(rules.risk.BaseScript) // line with error
import org.pysz.safebicycle.model.Calculator

class Cat extends Script implements Calculator {

    @Override
    Object run() {
        return null
    }

    @Override
    public int add() {
        return 4;
    }

    @Override
    public int multiply() {
        return 5;
    }
}
```

The line nr 2 gives me error message:

```
Annotation @BaseScript can only be used within a script
```

Well ok, its pretty understandable. But if I cannot use a @BaseScript inside a class how can I create a script/class which implements 2 abstract methods from an interface at the same time using a BaseScript which has some common methods and data?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I completely understand what you are trying to achieve...
But I don't think BaseScript is what you are looking for.

Mr. Haki has a blog post describing BaseScript:
https://blog.mrhaki.com/2014/05/groovy-goodness-basescript-with.html

(Edited based on comments below)
I think this is what you want:

Calculator.groovy

```
interface Calculator {
    int add()
    int multiply()
}
```

Cat.groovy

```
class Cat extends Script implements Calculator {

    @Override
    Object run() {
        return null
    }

    @Override
    public int add() {
        return 4;
    }

    @Override
    public int multiply() {
        return 5;
    }
}
```

Mouse.groovy

```
@BaseScript(Cat)
import groovy.transform.BaseScript

println "Hello " + add()
println "Hello world " + multiply()
```

Note that the import is after the BaseScript annotation.

Comment: I would like to create groovy script/class which 1) will set my CustomScript as base (this is the strong requirment) 2) at the same time I  want my script to have some structure. Meaning i want it to have 2 methods which I am sure are named the way I want and they take specific arguments and return specific value ( so basically implementing an interface would be a solution). Just I cannot achieve to combine those 1 and 2 together.

Comment: I have updated my answer.

I have placed the interface and the base class in the same file as the script for simplicity, they could off course be in their own files

Comment: That is a interesting point , but I want Cat to implement Calculator and import a BaseScript from a different file , containing some common data, which I wan to reuse. So not to set as basescript the same class which is using it (Cat class setting itself as basescript)

Comment: BaseScript is for

   "Variable annotation used for changing the base script class of the current script."

If you want to extend a class (and not a script) you should use inheritance and interfaces just like in Java or maybe a Groovy Trait http://docs.groovy-lang.org/docs/groovy-2.3.0/html/documentation/core-traits.html